# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android, sdk

Quero printar um "Hello World" na tela, criei um novo projeto com um nome qualquer no Android Studio, cliquei em "Run" e ele me retornou esse erro...

Verifiquei o AndroidManifest e tudo parece OK (adicionar sdkMin e sdkTarget e também não funcionou):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.saapc.meumapa" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".IndexAcitivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

No build.graddle tentei também alterar as configuração do SDK min e target, também sem sucesso...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.saapc.meumapa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Tentei instalar diversos SDKs e pacotes no SDK Manager, nada resolveu.
Em todos os sites ao qual via perguntas sobre este erro diziam para alterar o MinSkdVersion e o TargetSdkVersion.
Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente ao utilizar a versão L como `targetSdkVersion`, ele força com  que a `minSdkVersion` seja L também, independente se declarou seu `minSdkVersion` como 15.

Nesse caso você poderia usar o SDK 20 ou 19 como a `targetSdkVersion` ou seguir uma das duas alternativas para usar o SDK L Preview:

Para fazer o deploy da versão L, você precisa instalar seu apk em uma AVD com a imagem do L Preview, que está disponível no SDK Manager.

Ou instalar uma imagem do Android L, disponibilizada pela Google, em um dispositivo Nexus (5 ou 7 2013).

Para mais detalhes de uma olhada em https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html.