# Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+

Tags: android, gradle

Instalei o Android Studio, instalei o JDK, configurei as variáveis de ambiente (JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, PATH). Configurei meu proxy (fiz o teste e a conexão funciona), e ao tentar criar uma "Blank Activity" obtenho o seguinte erro:

**Error:Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
Required by:
    :MTeste:unspecified**

### build.gradle do projeto

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### build.gradle da aplicação

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.br.mteste"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

Não fiz nenhuma alteração nos gradles (quer dizer, evidentemente tentei diversas alterações, mas não houve sucesso em corrigir o erro então voltava ao padrão). 
Alguém sabe como resolver isso? 
Procurei o dia inteiro ontem e não encontrei nada que resolvesse isso... :/

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou abrir o SDK manager e atualizar todos os pacotes? Eu vejo que vc está usando api de suporte v7, então vc deve ter esse pacote instalado. Fora que vc deve tambem ter a o build-tools da versão que está declarada no gradle (que no caso é a 20), e tambem os pacotes da versão que vc está compilando (que no caso é "android L").

Comment: Quanto ao SDK Manager, acho estranho que só aparecem os que estão instalados (não consigo visualizar nenhum outro, mesmo pedindo para exibir todos os outros). Sobre os pacotes, eu tenho aqui as pastas "android-20" em "plataforms" e "android-4.4W" em "build-tools", encontrei também a "appcompat-v7" em "android-studio\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support"... Seria isso mesmo? Peço desculpas pela ignorância, mas em cursos e apostilas não ensinam nada disso :/

Comment: Eu não creio que o erro seja o Gradle, cuidado ao usar o SDK `L Preview`, dê uma olhada nessa pergunta que pode ajudar a resolver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25945/failure-install-failed-older-sdk. Tente trocar o repositório de `jcenter` para `mavenCentral` também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente remover o sinal de '.+' do classhpath do gradle.
Há uma pergunta respondida semelhante a esta, em inglês:
[problema semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708230/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-org-robolectricrobolectric2-3)

Comment: Já tentei diversas alterações referentes ao número da versão (0.12, 0.12.0, 1.12, entre muitas outras, todas sem sucesso). Eu encontrei a pergunta do link que passou, mas não consegui encontrar a resposta, entrei no link fornecido pelo homem que respondeu, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar por lá :(